# Rails same top-level URL route for organizations/user: domain.com/user and domain.com/organization works the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm attempting to make it so that top level-routing works from my Rails API to an Ember.js client in this manner (similar to how GitHub works, for example):

Hitting `www.example.com/username` would give you a user's page. This would either hit the `api.example.com/users/:username` endpoint or some other endpoint.

Hitting `www.example.com/organization_name` would give you an organization's page. This would either hit the `api.example.com/organizations/:organization_name` endpoint or some other endpoint.

When getting a random URL, the client will obviously have no idea what type of model it's dealing with. It will just treat it as `www.example.com/random_string`, where `random_string` is either a `username` or an `organization_name`.

I'm not quite sure how to deal with this situation. It's unclear where the responsibilities lie with client or server here. I can imagine maybe some sort of polymorphism working here, but can't connect the dots.

**EDIT**

It looks like this is ostensibly possible on the Rails side by having a catch-all route for `/:slug` and then using the slug to first query for a `User`, and then query for an `Organization`.

The bigger question, then, is whether it make sense to handle these requests by rendering with an existing controller action, or by letting HTTP handle it with redirections. Will `ember-data` handle the HTTP redirections well? And in the other case, will it be able to appropriately switch types on this endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It looks like this is ostensibly possible on the Rails side by having a catch-all route for /:slug and then using the slug to first query for a User, and then query for an Organization.

This is the only viable approach. You need at the very end of your *config/routes.rb* file to add this catch-all route. I advise you to associate this route to a *proxy* method in your controller which is going to determine if a `User` or an `Organization` record corresponds to the `slug`.

Knowing that you must consider the application action when a `User` and an `Organization` have the same `slug` (some will prioritise one of them, some will give the 2 choices to the visitor) ; and the action to take when no record correspond to the `slug` (some will display a 404, some will route to a listing page). Those choices will help you to determine the better design for your proxy method.

The main thing here is to design this *proxy* method.

**1- HTTP redirect**

Your *proxy* method will respond a `redirect_to` to */users/:slug* or */organizations/:slug* depending on what's found from the `slug`.

- Advantage: easy and fast to write and maintain.
- Disadvantage: slow application response due to the HTTP redirect and the need to re-access the database during the second request.

**2- Ajax response**

Similar to HTTP redirect, but done in AJAX. Your *proxy* method would display a page containing JavaScript code that fetch the content of */users/:slug* or */organizations/:slug* and display it through AJAX.

Additionally the URL could be changed by JavaScript using `history.pushState`

- Advantage: a little bit faster than above
- Disadvantage: but harder to write, necessitate JavaScript code plus js view, and it is still necessary to re-access the database during the second request

**3- Server side proxy**

Your *proxy* method would perform the same code as your endpoint method. Meaning that if the `slug` is found to correspond to a `User` record, the *proxy* method would do the same as `UserController#show`. (And same goes for `Organization`)

This means that the *proxy* method must call all before/after filters that `UserController#show` would, and render the same view.

Be very cautious if you choose this solution to DRY. Or you may end up with difficulties to maintain your app.

There is not a single method to do this, and it all depend of your application architecture. If for example your `show` method is just fetching the record and rendering the view, and if there is no controller helpers methods, than it's easy and safe. On the other hand if you have filters and controller helpers methods than it get a bit more tricky. In this case you may want to rely on controller Concerns.

- Advantage: fastest solution
- Disadvantage: can be very complex to write, and depending of the evolution of your code-base in the future, you may end up in a locking situation where you would be obliged to give up this design.

Answer (score 3):

## Create a model

Create a new model for routes, it will belong to a user, or an organization. Give it a unique string, and let it decide who it belongs to:

On the model:

```
def owner
    self.organization || self.user
end
```

On the organization and user:

```
has_one :route_name
before_create :create_route

def create_route
    self.create_route_name(path: self.path) #change this to what ever the user wants
end
```

Then you can do:

```
RouteName.find_by(name: "blah_blah").owner
```

Answer (score 2):

## Single Table Inheritance

Let's say we have a user, and an organization, we can do the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Organization < User; end
```

(you need a type field on the users table, which both users and organizations will share)

They will share database fields, and the Organization class will inherit everything the User has (including default scopes, and verifications). This is super useful if your models are alike, since you can keep everything DRY (you don't have to define anything extra).

```
Organization.create(name: "thisisanorganization") #=> true (assume that name is unique)
User.create(name: "penne12") #=> true (assume that name is unique)
User.find_by(name: "thisisanorganization") #=> Organization
User.find_by(name: "penne12") #=> User
Organization.find_by(name: "thisisanorganization") #=> Organization
Organization.find_by(name: "penne12")
```

You might also find it useful to create a parent class for the User and Organization, so users can have unique methods & verifications from organizations (password not needed on an organization, organizations belong to many owners (class: user), organizations must have a project, users have an email, etc)

[Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)